# Visual Studio 2005 application portability

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2005, build, executable, portability

I am creating an application (VS2005, C++ Forms application) that is supposed to work on many different machines that won't have any version of Visual Studio and I am wondering what I should worry about. I am using the Mysql connector, so apparently the machine running it will need to have some compatible version of MySQL, but appart from that, what else should I do to make it work? I'm sure that just giving out the .exe file in the project/release file won't suffice...

Edit: I tried running on a different machine (same .NET, same MySQL, even same Visual Studio), but if I try to run the.exe it gives me a error message saying: "This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem". I also tried building on it (desperate thought, because it doesn't have the connector) and it gave me the following output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Carna2e, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Copying 'f:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll' to target directory...
1>Build log was saved at "file://f:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Carna2e\Carna2e\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Carna2e - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

here is the build log, that is (like it should) the same with the output:

```
Build Log:
 Build started: Project: Carna2e, Configuration: Debug|Win32
 Command Lines      Copying 'f:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll' to target directory...
 Results      Build log was saved at "file://f:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Carna2e\Carna2e\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
Carna2e - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Fixed: Apparently I also had to have the connector installed...

Comment: Will you tell us what language/framework your application is developed in?

Comment: Mostly in C++, added it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum, the version of the .Net Framework that you write your application for needs to be present on the target machines.

MySQL would have to be present and configured for your application, unless you intend to run MySQL on a database server.

Other than that, you would only have to install more things if you use non-.Net libraries.

Comment: Since it is C++, the Visual C++ redistributable is required too. Alternatively, a merge module can be used if there is an installer.

Answer (score -1):

only thing you must be sure so you exe work is tha versoun of the framework you need is installed if you project is created with VS 2008 you need .net framework 3.5
Best Regards,
Iordan